# R System command working in R studio, but its not working in Rescript batch mode, is there any method to invoke vbs script from Rescript mode?

Tags: r, system, system2

I have below code in new.R file, which is working fine in RStudio interactive mode.

```r
system_command <- paste("WScript", " C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/r1.vbs")
system(command = system_command)
```

But when I run the `new.R` file using `Rscript`, its not invoking the vbs script. Is there any other way to invoke vbs script in Rscript mode?

Comment: What error message do you get? How do you invoke your R file? Did you specify correct path for Rscript?

Comment: Tangent: if you are certain that you will never have spaces or non-standard characters in your `vbs` filename, this may work, but if not you should really try to protect yourself from shell-isms. For instance, `system2("WScript", shQuote("c:/Users/..."))` is one start. Underneath it all, though, both `system` and `system2` are woefully inadequate when quoting arguments, as it just uses `paste` under the hood. A more robust option (imo) is to use `processx`, which properly passes arguments as-is without risk of space-delimited confusion.

Comment: Thank you both of you, it's working in RScript, the was stoping execution because of error before reaching to a system command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with system2() wenn i wanted to start a new Rscript-process in the background. R version 4.3.0 Windows 10
Programm works in RStudio, but not in Powershell: in Powershell no background process is started.
I added short slepp time in programm. This help.